# How to fix a constant validation accuracy in machine learning?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, computer-vision

I'm trying to do image classification with dicom images that have balanced classes using the pre-trained `InceptionV3` model.

```
def convertDCM(PathDCM) :
   data = []  
   for dirName, subdir, files in os.walk(PathDCM):
          for filename in sorted(files):
                     ds = pydicom.dcmread(PathDCM +'/' + filename)
                     im = fromarray(ds.pixel_array) 
                     im = keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(im)
                     im = cv2.resize(im,(299,299))
                     data.append(im) 
   return data

PathDCM = '/home/Desktop/FULL_BALANCED_COLOURED/'

data = convertDCM(PathDCM)

#scale the raw pixel intensities to the range [0,1]
data = np.array(data, dtype="float")/255.0
labels = np.array(labels,dtype ="int")


#splitting data into training and testing
#test_size is percentage to split into test/train data
(trainX, testX, trainY, testY) = train_test_split(
                            data,labels, 
                            test_size=0.2, 
                            random_state=42) 

img_width, img_height = 299, 299 #InceptionV3 size

train_samples =  300
validation_samples = 50
epochs = 25
batch_size = 15

base_model = keras.applications.InceptionV3(
        weights ='imagenet',
        include_top=False, 
        input_shape = (img_width,img_height,3))

model_top = keras.models.Sequential()
 model_top.add(keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D(input_shape=base_model.output_shape[1:], data_format=None)),
model_top.add(keras.layers.Dense(300,activation='relu'))
model_top.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))
model_top.add(keras.layers.Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid'))
model = keras.models.Model(inputs = base_model.input, outputs = model_top(base_model.output))

#Compiling model 
model.compile(optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(
                    lr=0.0001),
                    loss='binary_crossentropy',
                    metrics=['accuracy'])

#Image Processing and Augmentation 
train_datagen = keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
          rescale = 1./255,  
          zoom_range = 0.1,
          width_shift_range = 0.2, 
          height_shift_range = 0.2,
          horizontal_flip = True,
          fill_mode ='nearest') 

val_datagen = keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator()


train_generator = train_datagen.flow(
        trainX, 
        trainY,
        batch_size=batch_size,
        shuffle=True)


validation_generator = train_datagen.flow(
                testX,
                testY,
                batch_size=batch_size,
                shuffle=True)
```

When I train the model, I always get a constant validation accuracy of `0.3889` with the validation loss fluctuating.

```
#Training the model
history = model.fit_generator(
    train_generator, 
    steps_per_epoch = train_samples//batch_size,
    epochs = epochs, 
    validation_data = validation_generator, 
    validation_steps = validation_samples//batch_size)

Epoch 1/25
20/20 [==============================]20/20 
[==============================] - 195s 49s/step - loss: 0.7677 - acc: 0.4020 - val_loss: 0.7784 - val_acc: 0.3889

Epoch 2/25
20/20 [==============================]20/20 
[==============================] - 187s 47s/step - loss: 0.7016 - acc: 0.4848 - val_loss: 0.7531 - val_acc: 0.3889

Epoch 3/25
20/20 [==============================]20/20 
[==============================] - 191s 48s/step - loss: 0.6566 - acc: 0.6304 - val_loss: 0.7492 - val_acc: 0.3889

Epoch 4/25
20/20 [==============================]20/20 
[==============================] - 175s 44s/step - loss: 0.6533 - acc: 0.5529 - val_loss: 0.7575 - val_acc: 0.3889


predictions= model.predict(testX)
print(predictions)
```

Predicting the model also only returns an array of one prediction per image:

```
[[0.457804  ]
 [0.45051473]
 [0.48343503]
 [0.49180537]...
```

Why is it that the model only predicts one of the two classes? Does this have to do with the constant val accuracy or possibly overfitting?

Comment: Your training & validation sets are too small for effective training & stable validation respectively...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have two classes, every image is in one or the other so probabilities for one class are enough to find everything because the sum of the probabilities for each image is supposed to make 1. So if you have the probabilitie p for 1 class, the probability for the other one is 1-p.

If you want to have the possibility of classifing images not in one of those two class, then you should create a third one.

Also, this line:

```
model_top.add(keras.layers.Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid'))
```

means that the Output is a vector of shape(nb_sample,1) and has the same shape as your training labels

Comment: Okay that makes sense for the predictions, but do you know what the reason could be for the constant validation accuracy?

Comment: there is many reaon for a constant accuracy. The good point is that only your cross validation accuracy is constant. That means that even if you're learning on the train dataset, it doesn't change the classification of the images of the test set. The main reason for that is often that the two dataset are too small and thus too different from one another. go all the way to your 25 epochs and see if there is any changes. If not, try feeding the NN more datas

Comment: @student17 could you accept the answer to close the subject please